# Attaching an event to new element in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I need to duplicate a new row on the click of `+` button. That new row contains a `-` button which will in turn delete that newly created row. So the problem is I could attach a click event to that new `-` button.

Below is the ts which contains the form :

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, ElementRef }    from '@angular/core';
import { MailSegmentObject }    from './mailSegmentObject';
import { MailSegmentRule }    from './mailSegmentRule';

@Component({
  selector    :   'segment-form',
  templateUrl :   'app/html/createSegment.html',
  styleUrls   :   ['node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'],
  encapsulation : ViewEncapsulation.Native
})

export class CreateSegmentComponent {

counter : number = 0;
segment : MailSegmentObject = new MailSegmentObject();

addNewRule() : void {
    var origElem = document.getElementById("mandatoryRule");
    var copyElem = <HTMLDivElement>origElem.cloneNode(true);
    copyElem.setAttribute("id", "mandatoryRule_" + (this.counter++));
    copyElem.innerHTML += "<div class=\"col-sm-1\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" (click)=\"deleteRule(this)\">-</button></div>";
    origElem.parentElement.appendChild(copyElem);
}

deleteRule(elem) : void {
    console.log("asdasdasdasdasd");
    elem.parentElement.removeChild(elem);
}
}
```

and html is:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 15px;">
   <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Segment Name">Segment Name</label>
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-12">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="segmentNameInput" placeholder="Segment Name">
           </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Select Property</label>
         <div class="row rule" id="mandatoryRule">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
               <select class="form-control">

               </select>
            </div>
            <div  class="col-sm-3">
               <select class="form-control">

               </select>
            </div>
            <div  class="col-sm-3">
               <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="addNewRule(this)">+</button>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Kindly help me out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is written completely against the concept of angular2. You should use `*ngFor` on a collection of `lines`. Never ever -ever- use things like: `getElementById`, `cloneNode`, `innerHTML`, `appendChild`, `removeChild`.

My suggestion is that you take a closer look to the tutorials and cook book provided at [**angular.io**](https://angular.io), because I'm sorry, with the current state of your code, you are asking for a complete rewrite